# Cplex indexing a dvar with a dvar

Tags: constraints, cplex

I have a constraint in OPL in which I need a dvar like an index in another dvar, but CPLEX gives me an error. I try to avoid this error using logical constraint as explained in https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/threadTopic?id=2be2ec22-db4b-4a2c-b164-615b9f735dc9&ps=25. But now a receive this error:

```
Error 5002: Q is not positive semi-definite
```

This is the constraint:

```
forall(j in pat,k in gior,w in slotp) 
   vinc4: (k==t[j])*y[j,k,w] == 
           sum(g in giorni)(r[j,g,w+1]) + 
               sum(g in giorni)(l[j,g,w-1]);
```

Comment: Without any context, this short snippet is almost useless for debugging. You are probably multiplying two variables (or using something which is transformed like that) resulting in non-convexity / Q not psd. And without context it's hard to say more than that.

Comment: Your constraint is an equality constraint on terms that involve products of variables. That is not supported since such a constraint is never convex (either the <= or the >= direction is non-convex). See the CPLEX user manual about quadratically constraint problems. The convexity requirements are described there.

Answer (score 0):

If `t[j]` is a variable, the expression `k == t[j]` is not a constant, but it is the truth value of a constraint. This truth value is equivalent to a variable that is 1 if the constraint is true, and 0 if not.

It seems you multiply this 'variable' by another one, `y[j,k,w]`. So you end up with a quadratically-constrained model: a model in which some of the constraints contain quadratic terms.  CPLEX can solve these models only if they are convex, and, from the error, it is not the case here.

Comment: Hi, i finally solved this with logical constraint in this way: forall(j in pat,k in giorn,w in slotp) (k==t[j])=>(y[j,k,w] == sum(g in giorni)(r[j,g,w+1]) + sum(g in giorni)(l[j,g,w-1]));

Comment: Bur I have a question this logical constraint, works like an if then or like a logical operator (=>). Because A=>B is equal to not A or B, instead if then of language programming is differente because if the condition is verify you do something otherwise you do nothing, instead in a logical constest if the condition is False is possible that the conseguent happens.